# Is there a natural way to view the proof of Hilbert 90?

Tags: nt.number-theory, fields

I only know of one proof of Hilbert 90, which is very smart if not magical. See for example http://hilbertthm90.wordpress.com/2008/12/11/hilberts-theorem-90the-math/

Does anyone know of a more intuitive proof or know a good way to view the proof?

I have accepted the answer by Emerton, great thanks as well to David Speyer and Brian Conrad.

Comment: It says that there's no obstruction to etale descent for 1-dimensional vector spaces: line bundle for the etale topology is "same" as a line bundle for the Zariski topology in case of spectrum of a field (true for any scheme) and so has a basis.  Faithfully flat descent for quasi-coherent sheaves doesn't rely on Hilbert 90, and in the special case of line bundles and etale covers of spec of field it is precisely Hilbert 90.  For vector bundles gives "Hilb 90 for GL_n". Grothendieck points out the link somewhere (intro of sga1?).  That is a "good" way to view the meaning of the result.

Comment: Just one clarification: the weblink gives the special case of cyclic extensions in the language of norms.  So to make the connection with Grothendieck, conceptually one applies degree-2 periodicity of Tate cohomology for cyclic groups which identifies the norm thing (which is Tate cohomology in degree -1) with usual degree-1 cohomology. The latter provides the framework for the "usual" formulation of Hilbert 90, which in turn is a super-special case of grothendieck's ff. descent theory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the way pointing answer, it is a bit overwhelming though (T T).

Comment: @Tran: Brian Conrad allows others to flesh out his comments in the form of an answer. Since I find this particular comment very interesting, I hope that someone eventually will... (See the comments here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20925/finite-generation-of-the-mordell-weil-group-over-finitely-generated-fields/20928#20928 )

Comment: @Francois: I don't expect that someone would necessarily do that, though people can do as they wish "answers". I don't see anything wrong with Minh just having this connection in mind at a future time when learning Grothendieck's descent theory and group cohomology.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, I fixed my comment accordingly while you wrote your reply. I understand your motivation and I don't disapprove. I was mostly speaking for my own interest since I am unlikely to work out the details of your comment for myself. This is pretty far out of my area, so the expected gain doesn't motivate the expected work. However, I do enjoy being exposed to different topics and types of reasoning, which is why I would like to see some of the details fleshed out.

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that faithfully flat descent is a special case of Beck's theorem, which is a result in pure category theory. In other words, its content is entirely category-theoretic, rather than geometric.

Comment: Jim, I have no idea what Beck's Theorem is, but there must be some genuine input needed since fpqc descent is not generally effective for schemes (in contrast with qcoh sheaves and morphisms), as you know.  So I'm puzzled as to what kind of "entirely category-theoretic" fact could subsume Grothendieck's result.  Is it just some far-out axiomatization of the bare minimum about properties of faithfully flat tensor product on (abelian) module category, in which case is it just a fancy reformulation of Grothendieck's argument without a new idea? 

Comment: Thanks for the linking. My blog was teetering on the dead side (around 50 hits a day), but I've had a nice spike in views since you posted this.

Comment: Thank you for posting the question on your blog as well. 

Comment: @BCnrd Beck's monadicity theorem is about sufficient conditions for a functor to be monadic (gives rise to the Eilenberg-Moore category of a monad).  It is much like the Adjoint Functor Theorem, but for functors arising as the Eilenberg-Moore category functors of a monad. I would say its motivation is not contained in the fact that it is a generalization of Grothendieck's result (if one agrees that it is a generalization), as it is useful elsewhere. JBorger may be referring to conditions for the extension of scalars functor to be monadic.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is a proof of Hilbert's Theorem 90 in the case of cyclic extensions which
I think is fairly conceptual.  The key point (which is also at the heart of Grothendieck's 
very general version in terms of flat descent) is that if we want to verify that
a linear transformation has a certain eigenvalue (in our particular case, the eigenvalue
 of interest will be 1), we can do so after extending scalars.

The set-up: we have a cyclic extension $L/K$, with Galois group generated by $\sigma$,
and an element $a \in L$ of norm 1.  We want to find $b \in L$ such that $a = b/\sigma(b)$.
As in David Speyer's answer, rewrite this as the equation $a\sigma(b) = b$.

The map $b \mapsto a\sigma(b)$ is a $K$-linear transformation of the $K$-vector space
$L$, and we want to show that it has a fixed point, i.e. that it has $1$ as an eigenvector.
Well, we can verify this after extending scalars (the eigenvectors of a matrix don't 
change if we enlarge the ground field), and so we tensor up with $L$ over $K$.

Now $L\otimes_K L \cong L\times\cdots \times L$, an isomorphism of $L$-algebras,
and under this isomorphism the action of $\sigma$ on the left just becomes the cyclic permutation of factors on the right.  (To see the isomorphism, write $L = K(\alpha),$
as we may by the primitive element theorem. If $f(X)$ is a minimal polynomial of 
$\alpha$ over $K$, then $L \cong K[X]/f(X),$ and so $L\otimes_K L \cong L[X]/f(X).$
But over $L$, the polynomial $f(X)$ splits as $f(X) = (X-\alpha_1)\cdots (X-\alpha_n),$
where the $\alpha_i$ are all the conjugates of $\alpha$.  Choosing the labelling
appropriately, we may assume that $\alpha_i = \sigma^{i-1}(\alpha)$.  Then
$L[X]/f(X) = L[X]/(X-\alpha_1)\cdots (X-\alpha_n) \cong L\times\cdots \times L,$
and $\sigma$ does indeed just permute the factors.)

Under the isomorphism $L\otimes_K L \cong L\times\cdots \times L,$
the base-change of our linear transformation $b \mapsto a \sigma(b)$ is given by
$(b_1,\ldots,b_n) \mapsto (a b_n, \sigma(a) b_1, \ldots, \sigma^{n-1}(a) b_{n-1}).$
This transformation has the obvious non-zero fixed vector
$(1,\sigma(a),\sigma(a)\sigma^2(a),\ldots,\sigma(a)\ldots\sigma^{n-1}(a)).$
(Remember that Norm$(a) = 1$, and so the last entry is also just $a^{-1}$.)

Thus our original linear transformation (before extending scalars) has a non-zero fixed vector as well,
as required.

How does this relate to Brian Conrad's comment?  Well, the preceding argument
generalizes massively to Grothendieck's theory of faithfully flat descent, which
in particular shows that any quasi-coherent sheaf in the flat topology in fact
arises from a Zariski sheaf.  That may sound quite complicated, but what the argument
amounts to is precisely what we used in the preceding argument: If $A \rightarrow B$
is a faithfully flat map of rings, and we want to study the "spectral theory"
of a linear operator on an $A$-module, we can do so after extending scalars to $B$.
(Of course, one has to be precise about what "spectral theory" means when we are
working over rings that aren't fields.  This is where faithfully flat comes in:
it is the condition that extending scalars from $A$ to $B$ is exact, and takes 
non-zero modules to non-zero modules; this turns out to be exactly the right
generalization of the more naive notion we used above, that extending scalars
preserves the eigenvalues of a matrix.)

Finally, here is an aside about the relation with Galois cohomology:

In cohomological language, Hilbert's Theorem 90 is the statement that $H^1(Gal(L/K), L^{\times}) = 0$
for any finite Galois extension of fields $L/K$.  To recover the statement involving
norms, one proceeds as follows: if $Gal(L/K)$ is cyclic, with generator $\sigma$, 
and the norm of $a \in L$ equals 1, 
then $\sigma \mapsto a$ determines a $1$-cocyle on $Gal(L/K)$ with values in $L^{\times}$.
By the vanishing of $H^1$, this must be a coboundary, which means that there exists $b$
such that $a = \sigma(b)/b.$

The cohomological statement (which, as Brian Conrad pointed out, is still a very special
case of Grothendieck's general theory) can be proved by the same extension of scalars argument as above.

Comment: Thank you. It is really a through out and insightful answer.

Comment: Beautiful     !

Comment: Could you please add a few more details on why $\sigma$ permutes the factors of $L\times L\times ...\times L$ ? Because it is an $L$-left module algebra endomorphism of $L\otimes_K L$ of order $n$ ?

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe you should have written that the isomorphism $L\otimes_K L\to L\times L\times ...\times L$ that you are using is not some random isomorphism, but the one given by $a\otimes b\mapsto\left(a\sigma^{-0}\left(b\right),a\sigma^{-1}\left(b\right),...,a\sigma^{-(n-1)}\left(b\right)\right)$. This makes clear the statements below. And you don't need the (ugly and non-canonical) primitive element theorem to prove that this is an isomorphism, because injectivity is simply the linear independence of characters and surjectivity follows from injectivity by the power of linear algebra.

Comment: Dear darij, you are correct, but I have a personal phobia towards independence of characters, for some reason, and if you bring that result to the forefront, it pretty quickly leads to another proof of Hilbert's Thm. 90 (which is however not the one that I remember).
Hence I prefer to think in terms of primitive elements (which I don't find as ugly as you do; but I suspect I'm in a minority there!).

Comment: @darijgrinberg By the way, this isomorphism makes Galois extensions Hopf-Galois extensions.

Answer (score 27):

One argument I love is the following: let $L/K$ be a Galois extension with group $G$ and let $n\geq1$. One can show very straightforwardly that $H^1(G,\mathrm{GL}(n, L))$ classifies $K$-vector spaces $V$ such that $L\otimes_KV$ is isomorphic as an $L$-vector space to $L\otimes K^n$, up to $K$-linear isomorphisms; Serre does it in chapter X, §2, of his *Corps Locaux*. Now, linear algebra tells us that all such $V$'s are in fact isomorphic to $K^n$ as $K$-vector spaces, so we conclude that $H^1(G,\mathrm{GL}(n, L))$ is trivial.

This is, in fact, the same argument that Brian gave. Yet it is nice that the theorem becomes essentially a statement saying that all vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic :)

Also, other somewhat mystifying statements, like $«H^1(G,\mathrm{Sp}(n, L))=0»$ can be proved by exactly the same argument.

Comment: "without group G"?  Probably not. :)

Comment: It's strange because Proposition 4 in chapter X, §2 Corps Locaux depends on that  H1(G,GL(n,L))  is trivial.

Comment: Not that strange: One can prove first Galois descent for vector spaces, and that is what Mariano recalls implicitly, and then prove Hilbert 90. The argument runs as follows, given a $1$-cocycle $u:G\rightarrow \text{GL}_n(L)$ define a new action of $G$ on $L^n$ by setting $f_{\sigma}(x):=u_{\sigma}\cdot\sigma(x)$. Take the fixed vector space $W$ of this action and by Galois descent any $K$-basis of $W$ is an $L$-basis of $L^n$. The matrix given by this basis is invertible, and its inverse gives the $1$-coboundary equal to the given cocycle. See Bourbaki Algebra V Sec10, N 5, Prop.9, pp. 64-65.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a good way to think of the standard proof:

Let $L/K$ be a cyclic extension of degree $n$, with $\sigma$ a generator of $Gal(L/K)$. Suppose that $N(a)=1$, for $a \in L$.

Define the operator $\tau: L \to L$ by $\tau(b) = a \sigma(b)$. We have $$\tau^n(b) = a \sigma(a) \sigma^2(a) \cdots \sigma^{n-1}(a) b = N(a) b =b$$
so $\tau^n$ is the identity. Also, $\tau$ is $K$-linear. So, considering $L$ as a $K$-vector space, we have a representation of $\mathbb{Z}/n$ on $L$.

We want to show that this representation has a trivial summand. If we can show this, we are done; if $\tau(c) = c$ for $c \neq 0$ then $a = c/\sigma(c)$. As you will learn in any course on representation theory, the operator
$$\pi := (1/n) \left( 1+ \tau + \cdots + \tau^{n-1} \right)$$
 is the projector onto the trivial summand of $L$. The standard proof is to verify that $\pi$ is nonzero.

Comment: This is nice but it doesn't work in characteristic $p$ when $p|n$.  Fortunately the standard proof actually verifies that regardless of characteristic it's nonzero without the factor $1/n$.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $E/K$ is a Galois extension with group $G=\operatorname{Gal}(E/K)$.

Construct the crossed product algebra $E\rtimes G$, which is the $E$-vector space with basis the elements of $G$ turned into a $K$-algebra in the unique way such that $eg\cdot e'h=eg(e')gh$ for all $e$, $e'\in E$ and all $g$, $h\in G$.

It is easy to check that the $K$-algebra $E\rtimes G$ is simple. Wedderburn's theorem then tells us that all simple $E\rtimes G$-modules are isomorphic. A corollary of this is:

> **Theorem.** $H^1(G,E^\times)=0$.

Indeed, suppose $\phi:G\to E^\times$ is a $1$-cocycle. The $E$-vector space $V=E$ can be endowed in a unique way with an action of $E\rtimes G$ in such a way that $eg\cdot 1=e\phi(g)$ for all $e\in E$ and all $g\in G$. Since $V$ is one-dimensional as an $E$-vector space, it is a simple module over $E\rtimes G$ and it follows from Wedderburn's theorem that there is an $E\rtimes G$-linear isomorphism $f:E\to V$,for $E$ is also a simple $E\rtimes G$-module. If we set $y=f(1_E)$, then the coboundary of $y$ is $\phi$. $\Box$

More generally, from Wedderburn's theorem we get that *all*  $E\rtimes G$-modules are direct sums of copies of $E$, and that implies in pretty much the same way that $H^1(G,GL(n,E))=0$ (and the infinite dimensional version that Serre leaves as an exercise in *Corps locaux*)

Answer (score 6):

Another way to conclude that $\tau$ has a fixed point using linear algebra is the following. David Speyer shows that $\tau$ is of order $n$. But, thanks to independence of characters, the minimal polynomial of $\tau$ is $X^n-1$ and thus $\tau$ is a cyclic endomorphism of $L$. Hence 1 is an eigenvalue of $\tau$ with multiplicity one.